# Foreign Key with no Ids for column with same name as navigational property

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have the following tables.

```
CREATE TABLE Thing
(
    Id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1, 1),
    CreatedByUser INT NOT NULL
)
 
CREATE TABLE User
(
    Id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1, 1)
)
```

I have the following EF entities, defined (intentionally) with a navigational property without an Id.

```
public class Thing
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
 
    public User CreatedByUser { get; set; }
}
 
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to know how to define the foreign key relationship when the underlying Id field on the table is the same name as the navigation property I would like include on the entity model. *The following example fails to find a db column with the name CreatedByUser_Id.*

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Thing>()
  .HasOne(x => x.CreatedByUser)
  .WithMany()
  .HasForeignKey("CreatedByUser_Id")
  .IsRequired();
```

Thanks

Comment: Because in your table you called the column "CreatedByUser"?  Either rename the column in the table (recommended) or `.HasForeignKey("CreatedByUser")`

Comment: Thanks. I understand why, hence the question. If I set the foreign key in this way, it conflicts with the name of the navigational property.

Comment: Predictably, I get: "'CreatedByUser' cannot be used as a property on entity type 'Thing' because it is configured as a navigation."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it with the following.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Thing>()
    .HasOne(x => x.CreatedByUser)
    .WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey("CreatedByUser_Id")
    .IsRequired();

modelBuilder.Entity<Thing>()
    .Property("CreatedByUser_Id")
    .HasColumnName("CreatedByUser");
```

Comment: Yep, that was just what I was commenting on the question. ;) Ideally the schema should use a naming convention for FK names like CreatedByUserId or CreatedByUser_ID to avoid naming issues like this as well as make it clear in the schema that these values are expected to be FKs to other tables.